# The aisle seat is fine by me?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-usage

I found this phrase on a Mobil app,And I did not understand why it wrote "by me" and not "for me"

> - She: I will check if there is one available.
> - Me: if not,the aile seat is fine by me.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237992/fine-by-me-vs-fine-with-me

Comment: @Alex_ander:I guess you didn't understand my question .

Comment: The example link that you gave me is about by me and with me but my question is why in that phrase "by me" and not "for me"

Comment: "By me" in this context means something like "according to me", "in my opinion". You may think that "for me" would be more logical, but "That's fine by me" is just an idiom.

Comment: @Να είστε αισιόδοξοι OK. Considering more similarity between the versions 'fine with/by', here's an explanation of the difference between 'fine for/with' me, by Brian Hartman:
https://www.quora.com/Does-Its-fine-for-me-mean-exactly-the-same-thing-as-Its-fine-with-me "It's fine for me." means some particular thing (object) is satisfactory to you. A coat may be fine for you.  A cup of tea may be fine for you.  But it's a _thing_. "It's fine with me." usually refers to a _course of action_

Comment: So, in your example 'fine for me' would mean 'the aisle seat _suits_ me (personally)' (e. g. it's closer to exit), while the internal sense here is rather 'I _won't object_ to sitting on the aisle' if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely meaning 3 in the [Oxford Learners'](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/fine_1):

> (also used as an exclamation) used to tell somebody that an action, a suggestion or a decision is acceptable
>
> ‘Bob wants to know if he can come too.’ ‘That's fine by me.’

"Fine by me" is a phrase that simply means "I think that's acceptable".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, 'this seat seems fine for me' implies that I can seat (myself) in.

While 'this seat seems fine by me' implies that in my opinion, anyone (else) might seat in it.

Funny, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, language is sometimes strange, especially where idioms are involved. _Fine by me_ is an idiom meaning "I accept/approve/have no objection".

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.